# How to remove space and new line character "/n" present in a oracle column (project_name)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle Table that holds all the Project Details, This table (HR.AA_PROJECT_D) has a column project_name which has both white space and the new line character "/n" present in it, Is there a way to remove them both and update the Column? Since I have data security issues I will not be able to post the output here for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace: \n = CHR(10) and blank ' ' with '':

```
UPDATE hr.aa_project_d SET project_name=REPLACE(REPLACE(project_name,CHR(10),''),' ','');
```